# Python | BeautifulSoup | Выводит ошибку: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
groups_id = {'АВ-161': 316, 'АМ-161б': 313}
data_time = datetime.date.today()
links = []
def genlinks(groups_id, data_time):
    for i in groups_id:
        links.append(('http://almetpt.ru/2020/site/schedule/group/' + str(groups_id[i]) + '/' + str(data_time)))
def parsing():
    for link in links:
        page = urlopen(link)
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        title = page_soup.find(class_="header3")
        cards = page_soup.find_all(class_='card myCard')
        for card in cards:
            card_header = card.find(class_='card-header').text.split()
            print(card_header)
        cards.clear()
        page_soup.clear()

genlinks(groups_id, data_time)
parsing()
print(*links)
```

Пишу парсер для сайта, в функции def parsing() первый цикл for link in links выполняется и выводит ответ, а в следующем выводит ошибку атрибута. Вот что выводит консоль:

> ```
> ['I', 'пара', '0800', '-', '0925']
> ['II', 'пара', '0930', '-', '1055', 'большая', 'перемена', '25', 'минут']
> ['III', 'пара', '1120', '-', '1245', 'перемена', '10', 'минут']
> ['IV', 'пара', '1255', '-', '1420', 'большая', 'перемена', '20', 'минут']
> ['V', 'пара', '1440', '-', '1605']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/VK_bot/main.py", line 44, in <module>
>     parsing()
> File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/VK_bot/main.py", line 24, in parsing
>     card_header = card.find(class_='card-header').text.split()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Т.е. сначала все нормально, а потом что то уже не устраивает, помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: Ошибка означает что `card.find(class_='card-header')` вернуло `None`, а это означает что не найдено элементов с таким классом.

Comment: Со str.split() такая же ошибка, я проверила след. ссылку там класс card-header присутствует.

Comment: Значит не во всех блоках с классом card myCard есть блок с классом card-header. Например посмотрите в коде страницы после заголовка "Консультации преподавателей" - там идет див c `class="card myCard"`, а внутри него див `class="card-body p-0"`, блоков с классом `card-header` там нет (пример ссылки по которой смотрел: http://almetpt.ru/2020/site/schedule/group/316/2020-03-04).

Comment: Да действительно, внизу дальше есть card myCard, видимо слишком зациклилась на них вот и не увидела. Только вот проблема новая, как вытащить card myCard которые относятся только к предметам в расписании. Ладно, спасибо, буду дальше думать

Comment: Можно как раз проверять что `card.find(class_='card-header')` возвращает, и если `None`, то прерывать цикл.

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо, просто первый раз пишу серьзный для меня парсер, еще не все понимаю